# Fetch response with 404 page not found when deploying on Netifly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment

Im am quiet a beginner in webdev. I just deployed my reactjs app on netifly: https://bidimdepru.de/login . My problem is, when i do fetches i get a "Page not found". I cant figure out why this is happening, because locally everything works just fine? My backend is on deployed on Render.com under https://emptychat-backend.onrender.com/

I would really be happy, when someone can help me, because its my very first page i ever created :(

The Github repository is: https://github.com/zxmod51/React-Application and my Settings in Netifly are:
[Netifly Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3asnm.png)

I already created a _redirects-File with /*    /index.html    200 but fetches still doesn't work.

Comment: Why do all your external links point to `stackoverflow.com`? I've fixed them.

Comment: you should add code and error screenshots for others to better understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the development `proxy` incorrectly in a production environment.

### solution

1. just change all `fetch` requests on the client as shown in the code below.

```
- app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
+ app.post("https://emptychat-backend.onrender.com/login", async (req, res) => {
```

2. make sure that you have enabled `CORS` on your server-side

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
# OR
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://bidimdepru.de
```

### demo

```js
const API = `https://emptychat-backend.onrender.com`;

app.post(`${API}/login`, async (req, res) => {
  // ...
}
```

https://github.com/zxmod51/NodeExpress-Webserver/blob/main/app.js#L48

### refs

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: So, thanks for your respond. I did need to change my login fetch to fetch("https://emptychat-backend.onrender.com/login", requestOptions) in my React frontend and allow CORS in my nodejs backend! Thank you very much!